# Understanding Heron's formula proof

Tags: geometry

[image: The image is from professor George F Simmon's book precalculus mathematic in a nutshell]

I was trying to understand the proof of Heron's formula. I understood everything up to step $(d)$ except how they arrived at the expression ($a$+$b$+$c$)($b$+$c$-$a$)($a$+$b$-$c$)($a$-$b$+$c$) and the steps afterwards I still don't understand I would appreciate if someone gave me insight into how the expressions came about

Comment: I deleted my answer since question asker thought I didn't do enough steps.

Comment: @coffe math please help me you didn't have to delete I was asking for a clarification

Comment: I suggest you start at the third term on the right of (b) and multiply its numerator [product of 4 trinomials] all out completely. See if that matches the second term on the right of (b).

Comment: The answer by "I Eat Pork..." does all the steps. I think you should study it and then accept that answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help both of you

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

\begin{align}
h^2
&=b^2 - d^2\\
&=b^2 - \frac{(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2}{4c^2}\\
&=\frac{(2bc)^2-(b^2+c^2-a^2)^2}{4c^2}\\
&=\frac{(2bc+b^2+c^2-a^2)(2bc-b^2-c^2+a^2)}{4c^2}\\
&=\frac{\big[(b+c)^2-a^2\big]\big[-(b-c)^2+a^2\big]}{4c^2}\\
&=\frac{(a+b+c)(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)}{4c^2}
\end{align}